# multiple checkbox selection for displaying charts

Tags: javascript, postgresql, jsp, checkbox

I am creating charts using jfreecharts. Data is stored in PostGreSQL database. I am using jsp to connect postgresql for taking data from the database and display it using jfreechart and jsp.This is the code for display data filenames stored in the database

```
<div class="container">
    <%
        while (rset.next()) {
    %>
         <input type="checkbox" /> <%= rset.getString(1)%> <br />
    <%
        } //while loop ends here 
    %>
</div>
```

Now i am trying to do multiple charts display using checkboxes. If i select three checkboxes then three plots should be drawn on jfreechart, I already created code for display multiple selective charts using listbox.

This function is for select table name from list box and display it in jsp, its working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeSpecies() 
        {
            var checkBox = document.getElementById("selspecies");
            var checkedValue = checkBox.options[checkBox.checkedIndex].value;
            window.location.replace("bar6.jsp?name="+checkedValue);
        }
</script>
```

Now i want to create function for selection of three or more checkboxes. if i click the checkbox then it automatically displays the multiple plot on jfreecharts. How to create function for checkbox selection and create ids for calling the selected checkboxes then display operation happens? if anyone knows help me...

Answer (score 0):

Add a `form` element and place the `input` element inside the `form`

```
<form name="myform" action="bar6.jsp">

<div class="container">
    <%
        while (rset.next()) {
    %>
         <input name="mycheckboxes" type="checkbox" /> <%= rset.getString(1)%> <br />
    <%
        } //while loop ends here 
    %>
</div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeSpecies() 
        {
            document.myform.submit();
        }
</script>
```

In the server side use the `request.getParameterValues` to get the selected values

```
String selectedCheckboxes[]= request.getParameterValues("mycheckboxes");
```